# How to generate ssh key for another user in linux, and automate it in ansible

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scripting, ansible

I'm provisioning vagrant box by shell provisioner, which in turn executes ansible play against localhost. I'm using the following playbook

```
---
- name: Provision vagrant1 box
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: Install nmap
     apt: name=nmap state=latest update_cache=yes

   - name: Install sshpass
     apt: name=sshpass state=latest update_cache=yes

   - name: Generate ssh key
     shell: "ssh-keygen -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N ''"
```

Now the problem is, shell provisioner, thus ansible play is executed as root, where as I must setup ssh key for user vagrant and possibly other users.

Also, automating the ssh key creation and copying public key to known hosts feels clunky and fragile to be automated in the first place, as there maybe trust the server prompt and password input prompt, and passwords may vary. What is the best way of automating ssh key creation for different users and copy the public key to unknown amount of remote servers in ansible?

For those who are curious, my intend is to find all the remote servers on network with nmap and supply the password with sshpass to aid automating ssh-copy-id.

Comment: You may reformat/rewrite your question, as it's quite incomprehensible as is. Also, you may want to brush on [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of generating an SSH key for a user in an Ansible playbook is to use `generate_ssh_key` keyword of [the user module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html). That way the key is generated with the right permissions, and an existing key will not be overwritten (unless you wish to make it so):

```
---
- hosts: your_host
- user:
    ...
    generate_ssh_key=yes
    ...
```